# When to use observable and when to use resolvers to pass data through routing in Angular2

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I know there are three ways to pass data through routing in angular2: snapshot, observable and resolvers.

Snapshot is used when parameter value do not change.

How about observable and resolvers? What's the different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a resolver, your won't reach the page until the resolver is done. So in most cases, I prefer to use observables and watch router changes on my params so I can display some information on the page while the data are being loaded.

Of course, sometimes you might want to use a resolver.
Example : If your app is made of workspaces and within a workspace you can access to a property. You may want to wait until the workspace is loaded before you try to reach others properties.

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you need data.

If when path open: use resolver.

When you do something(getData method    for example): use observable.

PS A resolver is just a function that returns either Observable, Promise or just data.